# Не работает стиль кнопки в ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/interactivedesigner/2006"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource Button}"/>
                                <Button />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Grid Name="xGrid">
                            <Border>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="Button" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF000000" />
        </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Ребят, помогите решить задачку. Есть ResourceDictionary (содержание см. выше). Это отдельный файл. В App.xaml все подключено, все нормально.

Проблема заключается в следующем. Если в ResourceDictionary прописать стиль Button (`<Button Style="{StaticResource Button}"/>`), то проект не запускается и не выводит ошибки, нет так же исключений. VS выдает только сообщение:

[image: Ошибка]

А если без стиля у Button (`<Button />`), то все хорошо.

В чем может быть проблема?

**EDIT #1:**

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="View\MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**EDIT #2:**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    WindowStyle="None"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

            <Grid>
                <TabControl>
                    <TabItem Header="jhb">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
  </Window>
```

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится

Comment: Сейчас попробовал на другом компьютере на VS 2017, тоже самое - не работает. А без стиля - работает. :(

Comment: Значит в вопросе недостаточно информации для воспроизведения проблемы. Показывайте код App.xaml

Comment: Добавил. Но без этого стиля, остальные стили работают.

Comment: Я понял причину отсутствия ошибки у Вас. Попробуйте создать TabControl и TabItem. Выложил MainWindow.xaml. У меня на пустом проекте тоже все хорошо.

Comment: Ну добавляйте по частям разметку и определяйте на каком этапе начинаются проблемы

Comment: Так я так и сделал и определил, что ошибка в стиле: <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">. Конкретно при добавлении стиля Button'у Style="{StaticResource Button}". Но почему программа не работает, ведь все же синтаксически верно?

Comment: А если положить третий стиль перед первыми двумя?

Comment: Все гениальное - просто. Спасибо. :) Вот только почему исключения нормально не выводятся? Почему VS просто зависает и все?